# Recreating WinForms layout in WPF

Tags: wpf, winforms, layout

I've just inherited an old WinForms app with a UI layout like this:

[image: form layout]

I'm tasked with updating several things about the software one of which is porting it to WPF which I've not previously worked with.  I'm also told that the new WPF UI must look identical to the existing UI layout so I'm trying to figure out how to create that layout in WPF.  I need a toolbar across the top of the window which stretches the entire width of the fixed-size window.  Can I do that in the default grid or do I need a dockpanel to do that?  Also, I'm assuming that I would use a grid with 2 columns and 3 rows to layout the six groupboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you can do with a `DockPanel` can also be done with a `Grid` -- the `DockPanel` is just a shortcut. So yes, you can do all this with the default `Grid`.

As for how to do the layout: it depends on how you want things to resize. Does everything stay proportional when you resize? If so, a single `Grid` with three columns (and percentage sizes for the `ColumnDefinition`s) would be fine. You would actually need *four* rows, though, not three -- the first `RowDefinition` would be for the `ToolBar` (using `ColumnSpan="3"`) and would need `Height="Auto"` so it uses the `ToolBar`'s default size; the remaining rows would be percentage-sized.

Try that, see if it works for you. If the resizing needs to be more complicated than just proportional, then post a second screenshot of the window at a different size, and we could try to help you further.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use a `DockPanel` for the Menu/Content areas, then use a Grid in the Content Area to define the GroupBoxes

```
<DockPanel>
    <Grid x:Name="MenuRegion" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />

    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
</DockPanel>
```

Of course, you could also make the Menu area part of the Grid and set it to span all rows, but I personally like keeping them separate.

Answer (score 0):

Grid with 3 row (one for the menu).   Since you have uneven spacing in the rows just a single column on the main grid.  Then grid in the grid for the two column spacings.